# Unable to rake db:migrate in production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a user and granted it full access to the production database:

```
mysql> show grants for 'myuser'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myuser@localhost                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxxxxxxx' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myapp_production`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I rake `db:migrate`, I get:

```
** [out :: mydomain.com] Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

If I enter the root credentials into database.yml then it seems to work but I cannot use root user in production because of internal policies.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL message has an important pointer:

> Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

It tells you, that the client doesn't use a password. Apparently, you don't have the password configured correctly in the `database.yml` for your production db. Once you configure the correct password there, it'll work.

Comment: database.yml looks find - I can connect to mysql using those credentials... I do have a password specified in the database.yml

Comment: Can you do a manual mysql login using the `myuser` credentials directly on whatever is localhost (i.e., not remotely) and prove you can login that way?   If that works, it's gotta be the yml file; either the host or the stage or something isn't lining up the credentials.

Comment: thanks. +1. I went to that yml file, and a password was missing from block where it said "production". easy

Answer (score 1):

rails by default uses production environment so if you change db to some other environment .

i had the same error this worked

```
 bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```